# masstransit filter received message while consume

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a question, is it possible to create filter to prevent consume a message?
For example the message is:

```
public class ProcessingTask : IProcessingTask
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string ExternalId { set; get; }
    public ProcessingTaskStatus Status { set; get; }
    public string Details { set; get; }
}
```

So I need to pass message to consumer if message `Status` is `ProcessingTaskStatus.Received` for example. In another way the message need to be rejected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you can use the ContentFilter to filter out messages before they reach the consumer:

```
configurator.Consumer(() => _consumer, x =>
    {
        x.ConfigureMessage<IProcessingTask>(v => v.UseContentFilter(async context => context.Message.Status == ProcessingTaskStatus.Received));
    });
```

You have to setup a filter for each message type, they individually configured.

Comment: Does MassTransit 3 still have the UseContentFilter method? I can't find it. Or how can I not receive messages published from the same application? I am trying to synchronize data between multiple applications, and I don't want the application that published the message to also consume it.